# Two families of symplectic forms on a closed manifold and related isotopy

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Exercise 3.20 from "introduction to symplectic topology" by Mcduff&Salamon says

> Suppose that $w_t$ and $\tau_t$ are two families of symplectic forms on a closed manifold $M$ such that $w_0=\tau_0$ and $w_t$ is cohomologous to $\tau_t$ form all $t\in[0,1]$. Prove that for some $\epsilon >0$ there is an isotopy $\psi_t$ such that $\psi^*_t\tau_t=w_t$ for $0\leq t\leq\epsilon$.

So let me explain what I tried. Since $w_t$ and $\tau_t$ are cohomologous, (this means they represent a same class in $H^2_{dR}$), $\tau_t-w_t$ equals $d\sigma_t$ for some family of 1-forms $\sigma_t$. But at this point, we do not know if $\sigma_t$ is smooth with respect to $t$, so by the same method which appears in theorem 3.17 from the same book, we can choose $\sigma_t$ smoothly. (It uses induction over the number of sets in a good cover of $M$ as in Bott&Tu.) Now for each $t$, define $$\eta_{t,s}=w_t+s(\tau_t-w_t)=w_t+sd\sigma_t.$$
Here $s$ ranges from zero to one. Then there is a unique smooth family of vector fields $X_{t,s}$ which satisfies $\sigma_t+\iota(X_{t,s})\eta_{t,s}=0$ by nondegeneracy of $\eta_{t,s}$. (Actually, $\eta_{t,s}$ is still a symplectic form by convexity.) Since $M$ is closed, this $X_{t,s}$ is complete and by Moser's argument, we can induce a smooth family of diffeomorphisms $\psi_{t,s}$ such that $\psi^*_{t,1}\tau_t=w_t$. At this point, we define $\psi_{t,1}=\psi_t$ and the statement is done.

So I believe I did mistakes somewhere because $\epsilon$ cannot be always 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the general idea is correct. The only incorrect argument I've found here is:

> by nondegeneracy of $\eta_{t,s}$. (Actually, $\eta_{t,s}$ is still a symplectic form by convexity.)

A convex combination of symplectic forms is not necessarily a symplectic form. The easiest example is to take $(1-t)\omega +t(-\omega)$, for $t=\frac{1}{2}$.

In general, $(1-t)\omega_1 + t\omega_2$ is a closed form, but it's not necessarily non-degenerate. On the other hand, for closed manifolds, it is always non-degenerate for a small enough $t>0$.

Comment: Thanks, that was a critical mistake. Do you know any idea or hint how to proceed this problem?

Comment: Your original proof will work, just modify it to not assume that $\eta$ is defined for all $t,s$, and you will get the result.